# Problems to plot the fit of the regression line in ggplot2 (Ignoring unknown parameters: method)

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, linear-regression, data-modeling

I'm trying to graph the fitted simple linear regression line. However, for some unknown reason the line is connecting the points vertically. I am using the ggplot2 package and a warning message is appearing.

[image]

```
dados = read.table("dadosnew.csv", header = T, sep=";", dec=","); head(dados)
dados$Trat <- factor(dados$Trat)
dados$Teor <- factor(dados$Teor)
x11()
ggplot(dados, aes (x=Teor, y = massaseca)) + geom_point()+
  geom_line(method=lm)

ggplot(dados,
       aes(x=Trat, y = massaseca)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line(method=lm)+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 13,color="black"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 8,color="black"),
        legend.position = "none") + 
  geom_line(method=lm, se = F) 

Warning messages:
1: Ignoring unknown parameters: method 
2: Ignoring unknown parameters: method, se
```

I would like to have a single observation (the mean) in each treatment and a straight line adjusted to the means.

Comment: You need to use `geom_smooth` not `geom_line`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you had in mind?

```
 
ggplot(dados, aes(x = Trat, y = massaseca, group = Fator)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun = mean) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would also need the `group` option:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
dados = read.table("dadosnew.csv", header = T, sep=";", dec=","); head(dados)
dados$Trat <- factor(dados$Trat)
dados$Teor <- factor(dados$Teor)
#Plot
ggplot(dados,
       aes(x=Trat, y = massaseca)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method='lm',aes(group=1),se=F)+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 13,color="black"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 8,color="black"),
        legend.position = "none")
```

Output:

[image]